# Função focus JQuery não funcionando mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte função no meu código `.js`:

```
element = $('.bloco-pesquisa').find('#inp-pesquisa');

element.focus(function(){
    alert("focus!");
    if (!load_autocomplete){
        $.getScript('/js/jquery.typing-0.2.0.min.js');
        $.getScript('/js/autocomplete.js');
        load_autocomplete = true;
    }
});
```

Nos navegadores no computador funciona, já no `Chrome` ou outro navegador no tablet/celular não.

Alguém, sabe onde estou errando ou algum caminho para fazer funcionar?

Já tentei usar:

`.on('click touchstart', function () {`

`.on('click touch', function () {`

`.on('click touchend', function () {`

Nenhuma dessas opções funcionou.

Comment: os eventos `click touch*` tem uma função diferente do `focus`, mas se nem eles funcionaram, é bem provável que algum script javascript (seja jQuery ou não) esteja em conflito no navegador e esteja causando algum erro, fazendo com que o restante do JS pare. Teste no IE 9 (normalmente tem uma compatibilidade similar e causa os mesmos erros) e teste no mobile disparando o evento `.focus` manualmente: `document.getElementById("textBox").focus();`

Comment: Hmm. Obrigado, vou procurar se há algum erro anterior à esse código.